# Can you easily plot rugs/axes on the top/right in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following example has no inherent meaning... it's just meant to demonstrate particular placement of labels, rugs, etc. and is representative of [edited] *(a) a significantly larger project I'm working on that I can't discuss in detail, (b) which requires the use of ggplot, and (c) needs visual features of graphics similar to those reflected in the plot given, below.*

Is it possible to recreate the following using ggplot2 either directly or with some fiddling with grid?

```
x <- rnorm(20)
y <- rnorm(20)

plot(x, y, axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")

axis(side = 1, at = round(mean(x), 2))
axis(side = 2, at = round(mean(y), 2))

axis(side = 3, at = round( range(x), 2 ))
axis(side = 4, at = round( range(y), 2 ))

rug(x, side=3)
rug(y, side=4)
```

---

## Please see the solutions (Chase's, modified, and one based on Hadley's Geom code) posted below

Comment: What is the reason for wanting a ggplot2 solution? Is this just one of a series of panels you want to draw? If not, I don't see what is gained by ggplot2 or lattice over base graphics for something as simple as this and the lattice/ggplot equivalent will involve some amount of fiddling to achieve the same result. (IMHO)

Comment: Because, as I indicated, it's not that simple.

Comment: Because, as I indicated, what I need to achieve is not that simple, but the essentials are represented by this code. Telling me you don't think it can be done or done easily, I appreciate; that's potentially helpful. Telling me on the basis of an obviously greatly simplified test case that I shouldn't be considering the question is not helpful... it ignores the complex context my question is drawn from but, worse, assumes there IS NO context within which I'd need an answer to this question. I'm not trying to be snarky, but if we always assume there's a context, we'll get further faster.

Comment: @William the only indication of that is "larger project" and that can cover a multitude of sins ;-) What isn't "that simple"? The plot or the example of single data set? Unless you need ggplot2/lattice capability of drawing conditioned plots they are overkill for this. Now, if you want a plot to fit in with other existing plots you've already done in ggplot2 as part of this project, I can understand the Q.

Comment: The above was written before you edited your comment. I wasn't being snarky. I only asked for more context, because as it stands yours is a poor Q for exactly the reason of no context. @Chase has given a close attempt, but look at the fiddling required and it isn't correct yet (for the example you gave). Solutions are probably going to have to draw upon the wider context because lattice and ggplot2 are high level graphics engines and the bits of them that make them so useful are also the bits that make them difficult to work with when you go off piste.

Comment: It would have been wrong to say it can't be done or done easily without getting more context, and that was what I was asking for.

Comment: (1) comments should allow a return character; (2) As is often the case, I'm not at liberty to discuss the details. What's clear from my question, I hope (and if it's not, I need to be a better question writer), is that (a) what's asked doesn't reflect the full scope of the work, (b) the work requires the use of ggplot, and (c) critical features I need are represented in the example I offered. I hope it makes some sense that one should be able to pose a non-trivial question without having to justify or fully qualify/contextualize the question itself. See the "qualification problem", e.g..

Comment: Trivial questions are another matter :)

Comment: So what's wrong with saying "...of a larger project I'm working on that uses ggplot2 for the graphics/plotting."? That I understand. I wasn't the only one wondering why ggplot2 was required, so it wasn't obvious. I agree that providing endless detail/context in Q's is not useful, but getting uppity when someone asks for a bit more context isn't helpful.

Comment: @William: I think the issue was that (b) wasn't immediately clear in your question.  There are instances where people asked to solve a problem with a specific tool (for whatever reason) when the use of that tool wasn't *required* and without considering alternatives.  Gavin was trying to help you avoid unnecessary pain.

Comment: @Joshua: fair enough. Unfortunately (for me) I tend to be one of those people who says what he needs and needs what he says -- I read too much Dr. Seuss at an early age! So, when I post a ggplot question, it's not possible that I don't need ggplot, although I understand your point and have seen many questions that make the error of presupposing a given tool.

Comment: @Gavin: Nothing is wrong with it; I just didn't do it, given that I had already tagged it as a ggplot question. Unfortunately, as Joshua points out, just because someone claims to need a given tool does not mean that they _really_ need that tool. I just tend to be more exacting than that (although others have a different word for it ;) )

Comment: @Gavin: and... if you read this thread, I don't think there's "uppity" in here... that interpretation is entirely due to the loss of audio/visual cues in computer mediated communication. Re-read my comments, assuming I'm not trying to be difficult, and I hope you'll see that they're just meant to be feedback on how to give feedback, constrained by ASCII and 500 character limits.

Comment: @William Thanks for updating the Q (+1). Some of the comments/edits have been passing in the ether. I certainly asked my original comment in the spirit of @Joshua's comment above. There is a tendency to use it as it is the cool new kid on the block when it isn't always the most useful tool in many cases. Don't get me wrong, I really like ggplot2 and I use it all the time, it is just my experience that the high-level nature of ggplot often makes a custom plot like the one you want more difficult to produce.

Comment: @William Excellent work with the modification of @Chase 's Answer. be good to either get Chase to fix his answer or supply your own answer so something can be accepted here, for future reference and all.

Comment: @Gavin: done... just need to wait for SO to allow me to accept it in 24hrs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Accepted Solutions

---

### Chase's Answer (Modified)

Chase's answer had a few Xs and Ys out of place, causing the top/right axes to float unexpectedly... Here's an updated version of it:

```
xxx <- function(x, y) {

 p <- qplot(x,y) + 
    geom_segment(data     = data.frame(x), 
                 aes(x    = x, 
                     y    = max(y) + .05, 
                     xend = x, 
                     yend = max(y) + .1  )) +     #top-ticks

    geom_segment(data     = data.frame(x), 
                 aes(x    = min(x), 
                     y    = max(y) + .1, 
                     xend = max(x), 
                     yend = max(y) + .1  )) +     #top-axis

    geom_segment(data     = data.frame(y), 
                 aes(x    = max(x) + .1, 
                     y    = y, 
                     xend = max(x) + .05, 
                     yend = y)) +                #right-ticks

    geom_segment(data     = data.frame(y), 
                 aes(x    = max(x) + .1, 
                     y    = min(y), 
                     xend = max(x) + .1, 
                     yend = max(y)     )) +      #right-axis

    scale_x_continuous(breaks = NA) +   
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NA) +
    xlab(NULL) +
    ylab(NULL) +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(mean(x), 2), 
                  x     = mean(x), 
                  y     = min(y) - .2), 
              size = 4) +

    geom_text(aes(label = round(mean(y), 2), 
                  x     = min(x) - .2, 
                  y     = mean(y)), 
              size = 4) + 

    geom_text(aes(label = round(max(y), 2), 
                  x     = max(x) + .5, 
                  y     = max(y) + .0),        
              size = 4) +                   #right-max

    geom_text(aes(label = round(min(y), 2), 
                  x     = max(x) + .5, 
                  y     = min(y) - .0),         
              size = 4) +                    #right-min

    geom_text(aes(label = round(max(x), 2), 
                  x     = max(x) + .0, 
                  y     = max(y) + .2),        
              size = 4) +                   #top-max

    geom_text(aes(label = round(min(x), 2), 
                  x     = min(x) + .0, 
                  y     = max(y) + .2),         
              size = 4)                     #top-min

}

x <- rnorm(20)
y <- rnorm(20)

(xxx(x, y))
```

---

### Solution Based on Hadley's Code

See:  https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Creating-a-new-geom

Beginning with Hadley's geom-rug.r, essentially, I've changed only the location of the rugs by tweaking these two (partial) lines:

From

```
         y0 = unit(0, "npc"), y1 = unit(0.03, "npc"),
```

to

```
         y0 = unit(1.02, "npc"), y1 = unit(1.05, "npc"),
```

and from

```
         x0 = unit(0, "npc"), x1 = unit(0.03, "npc"),
```

to

```
         x0 = unit(1.02, "npc"), x1 = unit(1.05, "npc"),
```

---

```
 library(ggplot2)

 GeomRugAlt <- proto(Geom, {
   draw <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, ...) {  
     rugs <- list()
     data <- coordinates$transform(data, scales)    
     if (!is.null(data$x)) {
       rugs$x <- with(data, segmentsGrob(
         x0 = unit(x, "native"), x1 = unit(x, "native"), 
         y0 = unit(1.02, "npc"), y1 = unit(1.05, "npc"),
         gp = gpar(col = alpha(colour, alpha), lty = linetype, lwd = size * .pt)
       ))
     }  

     if (!is.null(data$y)) {
       rugs$y <- with(data, segmentsGrob(
         y0 = unit(y, "native"), y1 = unit(y, "native"), 
         x0 = unit(1.02, "npc"), x1 = unit(1.05), "npc"),
         gp = gpar(col = alpha(colour, alpha), lty = linetype, lwd = size * .pt)
       ))
     }  

     gTree(children = do.call("gList", rugs))
   }

   objname <- "rug_alt"

   desc <- "Marginal rug plots"

   default_stat <- function(.) StatIdentity
   default_aes <- function(.) aes(colour="black", size=0.5, linetype=1, alpha = 1)
   guide_geom <- function(.) "path"

   examples <- function(.) {
     p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg))
     p + geom_point()
     p + geom_point() + geom_rug_alt()
     p + geom_point() + geom_rug_alt(position='jitter')
   }


 })

 geom_rug_alt <- GeomRugAlt$build_accessor()

 x <- rnorm(20)
 y <- rnorm(20)

 p <- qplot(x,y)
 p
 p + geom_rug() + geom_rug_alt()
```

Answer (score 7):

I'll echo @Gavin's question, but for the sake of fiddling, this should get you pretty close:

```
qplot(x,y) + 
    geom_segment(data = data.frame(x), aes(x = x, y = max(x) - .05, xend = x, yend = max(x))) +         #x-rug
    geom_segment(data = data.frame(x), aes(x = min(x), y = max(x), xend = max(x), yend = max(x))) +     #x-rug
    geom_segment(data = data.frame(y), aes(x = max(x) + .05, y = y, xend = max(x), yend = y)) +         #y-rug
    geom_segment(data = data.frame(y), aes(x = max(x) + .05, y = min(y), xend = max(x) + .05, yend = max(y) )) + #y-rug
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = NA) +   
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NA) +
    xlab(NULL) +
    ylab(NULL) +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(mean(x),2), x = mean(x), y = min(y) - .2), size = 4) +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(mean(y),2), x = min(x) - .2, y = mean(y)), size = 4) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = round(max(x),2), x = max(x) + .2, y = max(y) + .2), size = 4)
    #...add other text labels to your heart's desire.
```

If you don't need to put the rugs on the top and on the right, you can take advantage of `geom_rug()`. I don't know of an easy way to "move" the x or y axis away from their predefined locations. Something like this may be easier to digest / work with:

```
df <- data.frame(x,y)
qplot(x,y, data = df, geom = c("point", "rug")) # + ...any additional geom's here
```

Comment: @Chase, close indeed... but I know which plot I'd prefer to fiddle with.

Comment: @Gavin - completely agreed, though some of that ugliness could be wrapped up into an R function. I'm hoping someone will stop by and show off some grid editing skills and put Appendix C of Hadley's book to good use...I've read it a few times and still can't really wrap my head around it. On a related note, where are "rugs" commonly seen/ I haven't run across them in any of my work, but I could see them being helpful for certain applications.

Comment: An interesting solution... I'm pretty sure I could make that work. Thank you!

Comment: Rugs are handy to show simple distributions, particularly with ggplot's support of alpha... I figured there would be a solution that could use SegmentGrobs or some such, but that seemed needlessly low level... particularly since choosing a side for the rug to plot on is so (high level) simple in base graphics. I'd love to see other solutions, if anyone has one.

Comment: In addition to @William's comment on rugs, they (rugs) tend to be useful when you aren't showing the data directly (smooth functions fitted to them) or when it isn't easy to identify the univariate distribution of observations when displaying bivariate data (as in William's data/example).

Comment: @Chase: That there isn't an easy way to put rugs on the top/right in ggplot (default) is precisely one of my problems. :)

Comment: @William - Nice work updating / fixing my buggy code. I butchered it when trying to go from my editor to SO. Since you've gone ahead and made a function out of it, I'd also suggest passing in additional parameters to control the height of the "rugs" and the number of decimals in the rounding if you may need more precision / details later. Nice work!

Comment: In the ggplot spirit, I'm also currently working through https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Creating-a-new-geom