# How can I add second axis labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Building on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183292/how-can-i-remove-empty-factors-from-ggplot2-facets) I'd like to add second axis label on the opposite side of the plot.

The data frame looks like:

```
test <- structure(list(characteristic = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor3"), class = "factor"), 
    es = c(1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.3, 1.5), ci_low = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 
    1.2, 1.4), ci_upp = c(1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.4, 1.6), label = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 5L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("1.2 (1.1, 1.3)", "1.3 (1.2, 1.4)", 
    "1.4 (1.3, 1.5)", "1.5 (1.4, 1.6)", "1.6 (1.5, 1.7)"), class = "factor"), 
    set = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("H", "S"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("characteristic", "es", 
"ci_low", "ci_upp", "label", "set"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Using [Tyler's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000343/tyler-rinker), a graph of it looks like that at the moment:

[image]

In a similar way to a forest plot I'd like to add a second set of labels (`label` variable in my data frame) representing graphed values, preferably on the right side of panels. So that it all mimics forest plot similar to this example:

[image]

I know that second axis [seems to be frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/how-to-use-ggplot2-make-plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another). However these are just another set of labels.. ant it seems to be a custom among forest plots.

How can I do that in ggplot?

Comment: the answers here will maybe give you a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867597/can-you-easily-plot-rugs-axes-on-the-top-right-in-ggplot2/4868130#4868130

Comment: @Chase: Thanks for that. Indeed much easily hackable using `plot`. Still wondering if one could do that in ggplot2?

Comment: The second axis is only frowned upon when it is a totally different variable (e.g. temperature and sediment concentration). A second axis which is a transformed version of the first is perfectly acceptable (e.g. temperature in C, or in K, or in F).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT** updating to ggplot2 0.9.3

Adding your set of labels in your test dataframe to the faceted chart is straightforward. Use `geom_text` with aesthetics for the labels, and the x and y positions of the labels. In the code below, `xlim` creates a little more space for the labels. The following code:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(test, aes(y = characteristic, x = es, xmin = ci_low, xmax = ci_upp)) + 
  geom_point() +   
  geom_errorbarh(height = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, x = 2, y = characteristic)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 2.2), breaks = c(1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8),
    labels=c("1.0", "1.2", "1.4", "1.6", "1.8")) +
  facet_grid(set ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
p

grid.text(expression(paste("ES " %+-% " ci")), x = 0.78,   y = .92,
   gp = gpar(fontsize = 18))
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:
( I am undeading the post due to not a complete answer found. I am still searching to add "diamond" Summary )

It is a lot "automated".

- lgOR     = Data with Estimates and CI 95%.
- ci_lower = 95% CI lower
- ci_upper = 95% CI upper
- author   = Authors / dates
- Model_pars  <- paste( orH2, ort2, orI2, orModel, orModel_sig, sep=" | ") # These are the Heterogeneity stats - as subtitle.

  ```
   min_v     <- floor(min(lgOR$ci_lower))
   max_v     <- ceiling(max(lgOR$ci_upper))
   OR_v      <- as.matrix( round(lgOR$OR,2) )
   ORci      <- paste("(", round(lgOR$ci_lower,2), "|", round(lgOR$ci_upper,2), ")" )

   ggplot(data=lgOR, aes(y=1:nrow(lgOR), x=OR, xmin=ci_lower, xmax=ci_upper)) +
     geom_point() + 
     geom_errorbarh(height=.3) +
     scale_y_continuous(name = "", breaks=1:nrow(lgOR), labels=lgOR$author ) +
     scale_x_continuous(limits = c( min_v, max_v + 3 ), 
                        breaks = c( min_v:max_v, max_v + 3 ),
                        expand = c(0,0) )+
     labs(title='Effect Size by Study', x=Model_pars, y = 'Study') +
     geom_vline(xintercept=0, color='black', linetype='dashed', alpha=.5) +
     theme( axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 1)) +
     geom_text(aes(x=9, label= paste(OR_v, ORci )))
  ```