# ggplot2: axis markers when grouping by two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple bar graph in ggplot, with two factor variables on the x axis:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(group1= c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                  group2= rep(1:4,4),
                  val = 1:16)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=group1,y=val,group=group2))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

What is the simplest way to add a second x axis label (for group2)?  There is a more complex version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183888/how-can-i-add-second-axis-labels-in-ggplot2), but I don't see how to apply this logic to this simple case.

Comment: Do you mean this: [Multi-row x-axis labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571306/multi-row-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot-line-chart)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571306/multi-row-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot-line-chart) posted by Jimbou, one solution is:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y=val,x=group2))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(.~group1,scales="free")
```

I'd be curious to know whether there is another solution using `annotate`, as also suggested in that question, that works in the case in which the grouping variables are two factors.

Comment: There is `switch` parameter in `facet_grid` since `ggplot2` version >= 2.0, using `facet_grid(.~group1,scales="free", switch = "x")` would look like adding second x-axis